# Embedding Glyphicons in CSS as data-uri

Tags: css, glyphicons, data-uri

I have a web application that uses Glyphicons, but the client is restricted from downloading fonts.

I found a page that says you can convert to uri the Glyphicon files and embed them in the Bootstrap CSS, which I did.

(partial listing)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: "data:application/octet-stream;base64,n04AAEFNAAAC.......
```

When I test it on the server, I get only a box where the glyph should be. Did I miss a step?

The application does use SASS-- could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in your listing snippet:

- `src` dataURI value must be inside `url()` 'function',
- it must have either correct mime type instead of `application/octet-stream`: e.g. `application/font-woff`,
- or corresponding `format()` declaration: e.g. `format('woff')`. Or better both.

Correct template should look like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: '[name]';
    src: url(data:font/[mime-format];base64,...) format('[css-format]');
    /* font-weight, font-style, ... */
}
```

SASS should not be the problem for resulting snippet as long file is `.scss` and not `.sass`.